# React and UI updates on data changes (via backend)

Tags: reactjs

Learning a little React currently. I'm finding myself confused about some of the utility here. One sticking point that seems to (for me, at least) undermine it's value is that If I want to sync my UI to data residing on the server (which can and will change), I need to manually poll the server? Aside from component-based architecture, I'm not sure how this is getting me further than well structured and logically implemented AJAX. Even in the React docs, they're using JQuery in this regard. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#updating-state

I'm sure I'm missing the forest for the trees or whatever. 
Thanks!

Comment: perhaps this is what Flux is about, but I didn't want to jump the gun there

Comment: ever tried to eat your soup from a bowl without a spoon and was confused about some of the utility here? some tools are meant to be used together with other tools..

Answer (score 4):

React is (citing [their page](https://facebook.github.io/react/))

> a javascript library for building user interfaces

The main focus is to build a view layer for your application. This means you have full freedom in choosing what to use to fetch your data. For simple uses it can be jQuery or [fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org).

It's generally recommended to not fetch data directly in your components and use one of Flux pattern implementations, e.g. [Redux](http://redux.js.org).

If your application has to be constantly powered by new data from server you can think about using something like [RethinkDB](http://www.rethinkdb.com) on your backend and connect it to Flux store on your frontend.